# NoClassDefFoundError Dynamic Web Project Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, servlets

I have a Java web project which inside a .jar file as external Library added through `Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Add external jars`. This jar it's been built using Maven's `clean install` argument and it uses `org.apache.httpcomponents` library added as dependency in his own pom.xml file.

Every time I try to invoke a certain url route to execute a Servlet which inside that jar invocation, I get this error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.name.MyClass`

The invocation is shown below:

```
import my.package.name.MyClass;
...
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException
{
    ...
    MyClass mc = new MyClass();//<- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException
    ...
}
```

`MyClass` is a simple HTTP Client which has to send an HTTP request to an HTTP Server.

This is what I'm doing: Right click on the project -> Run on server -> [shows the index.jsp] -> Click on a button inside the index -> Exception

The stacktrace as requested:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: my.package.name.MyClass
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1720)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1571)
at my.servlet.package.name.doGet(MyServletClass.java:45)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:624)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:957)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:423)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1079)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:620)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:318)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Please share stacktrace.

Comment: Answer update? or question update?

Answer (score 0):

If you've used `mvn install` to build the jar that the project is using, add it to your `pom.xml` instead of the build path.

The `install` part of maven will install it in your local repository and you can then include it in your pom.

I think you can also add the jar to be exported on the exports tab of the build path configuration, but I would use Maven to import the project from your local repo.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. But it behave in the same way even though I export as runnable jar with Eclipse. What's the difference between these two ways?

Comment: Use the maven way if you're exporting projects, the build path export means that those libs are made available to other dependent projects in Eclipse.  Honestly I'm not sure how that translates to an exported jar.  I know if you use maven the `mvn package` will generate the correct war file.

Comment: Seriously, I love Eclipse... but sometimes i would strike him with my fist... restarting the problem was solved. Probably a "Clean" was sufficient.